# Android Canvas How to scale Bitmap but keep original bound?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, scale

I want to scale a Bitmap using Canvas

I need to keep the Bitmap original width and height

and the scaled one aligns center-middle in bound

[image]

here is what I have tried:

```
public Bitmap scale(Bitmap src) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    float scaledWidth = width * .5f;
    float scaledHeight = height * .5f;

    Bitmap transBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(transBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    float dx = (width - scaledWidth);
    float dy = (height - scaledHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, null, new RectF(dx, dy, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), paint);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, true);

    //return transBitmap;
    return output;
}
```

I used this method in custom ImageView onTouch:

```
 switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            setImageBitmap(scaledBmp);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setImageDrawable(originalDrawable);
            break;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

MyImageView.java

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private Drawable mScaled;

    public MyImageView(Context context, Drawable drawable) {
        super(context);
        setImageDrawable(drawable);
        Bitmap src = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        mDrawable = drawable;
        mScaled = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), makeScaled(src));
    }

    public Bitmap makeScaled(Bitmap src) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        float scaledWidth = width * .95f;
        float scaledHeight = height * .95f;
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, true);
        Canvas xfas = new Canvas(output);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        xfas.drawBitmap(output, 0, 0, paint);

        return output;
    }

    @Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                setImageDrawable(mScaled);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I have not misunderstood, one solution is to use a `Matrix` and its setRectToRect to translate the original values to the desired one. From the documentation

> Set the matrix to the scale and translate values that map the source
>   rectangle to the destination rectangle, returning true if the the
>   result can be represented.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeigth), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, true);
```

and then simply draw the scaled bitmap on your canvas

Comment: I tried, but the bitmap just zoomed and got blurred and the size still same as previous one

Comment: I can't see where you are using the matrix

Comment: you have also to draw the bitmap

Comment: and probably you don't want to draw also src but only output

Comment: what you mean "also to draw bitmap"?

Comment: `canvas.drawBitmap(output,...)` ?

Comment: is it `canvas.drawBitmap(output, null, new RectF(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), paint);`?

Comment: `canvas.drawBitmap(output, 0, 0, paint);` should be enough, and remove   `canvas.drawBitmap(src,...)`

Comment: if you draw the bitmap on canvas that has the same size of the bitmap itself, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: like my picture demonstrated, I need the scaled down size bitmap centered in same size bitmap, but no idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap src, float factor) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    int scaledWidth = (int) (width * factor);
    int scaledHeight = (int) (height * factor);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, false);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int distX = (width - scaledWidth) / 2;
    int distY = (height - scaledHeight) / 2;
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, distX, distY, paint);
    return bmp;
}
```